# Why do I still have compressed data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ruby, compression

How can I decode received web-socket data. I will show you two code examples, Python and Ruby. At first, this is web-socket received raw data:

if I am using **Ruby**('faye/websocket'&'eventmachine'):

```
[31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 53, 206, 177, 13, 194, 48, 20, 69, 209, 251, 252, 191, 109, 8, 16, 69, 8, 9, 165, 97, 2, 87, 41, 89, 33, 18, 29, 19, 192, 18, 76, 192, 60, 217, 34, 179, 144, 150, 1, 136, 11, 244, 138, 219, 156, 226, 189, 64, 111, 196, 131, 120, 110, 245, 85, 40, 178, 34, 159, 137, 79, 210, 64, 46, 218, 12, 108, 47, 52, 39, 118, 13, 123, 56, 64, 11, 38, 28, 8, 53, 89, 159, 117, 161, 247, 222, 173, 163, 195, 39, 155, 44, 94, 185, 121, 130, 163, 103, 184, 187, 248, 179, 69, 139, 172, 90, 175, 54, 86, 155, 180, 30, 200, 163, 143, 254, 3, 73, 113, 41, 98, 142, 0, 0, 0]
```

and **Python**(import asyncio/):

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x035\xce\xb1\r\xc20\x14E\xd1\xfb\xfc\xbfm\x08\x10E\x08\t\xa5a\x02W)Y!\x12\x1d\x13\xc0\x12L\xc0<\xd9"\xb3\x90\x96\x01\x88\x0b\xf4\x8a\xdb\x9c\xe2\xbd@o\xc4\x83xn\xf5U(\xb2"\x9f\x89O\xd2@.\xda\x0cl/4\'v\r{8@\x0b&\x1c\x085Y\x9fu\xa1\xf7\xde\xad\xa3\xc3\'\x9b,^\xb9y\x82\xa3g\xb8\xbb\xf8\xb3E\x8b\xacZ\xaf6V\x9b\xb4\x1e\xc8\xa3\x8f\xfe\x03Iq)b\x8e\x00\x00\x00'
```

So, this is Ruby code:

```
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'permessage_deflate'
require 'zlib'

EM.run do
  ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new(
    "wss://wss.winline.ru/data_ng?", 
    [],
    :extensions => [PermessageDeflate]
  )

  ws.on :open do |event|
    p [:open]
    ws.send "lang"
    ws.send "AQ==" 
    ws.send "data" 
    ws.send "WINLINE" 
    ws.send "getdate" 
    ws.send "no_fordata" 

  end

  ws.on :message do |event|
    gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(event.data.pack('c*')))    
    puts gz.read
  end

  ws.on :close do |event|
    p [:close, event.code, event.reason]
    ws = nil
  end
end
```

To decode this data `[31, 139, 8..]` I used at first **method** **pack('c*')** with directive `c*`, maybe its wrong directive([found here](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Array:pack)) and then `Zlib::GzipReader.new`, so now I have the following data:

```
0k��0l��0���0���0���0���0���0���0���0���0���0���0���0���0���0���0���0���0���0���0��0�0�0���0���0���0���0Bhttps://player.twitch.tv/?channel=esbbasketball1&parent=winline.rue��Bhttps://player.twitch.tv/?channel=esbbasketball3&parent=winline.run��3https://bigsports.servicecdn.ru/streams/9952_499736���2154391���
38272563���Ahttps://player.twitch.tv/?channel=gt_sports_tv2&parent=winline.ru���Ahttps://player.twitch.tv/?channel=gt_sports_tv1&parent=winline.ru���0
```

Its still decoded, but now u can see links and other.

Then I decide to use Python, here is code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import gzip

async def echo():
    """Connect to socket, send message&get response"""
    uri = "wss://wss.winline.ru/data_ng?client=site"
    async with websockets.connect(uri, extra_headers=headers) as websocket:

        await websocket.send("lang")
        await websocket.send("AQ==")
        await websocket.send("data")
        await websocket.send("WINLINE")
        await websocket.send("getdate")

        response = await websocket.recv()
        print(response)
        content = gzip.decompress(response)
        print(unpack_from('hhl', response, 0))
        print(unpack_from('hhl', content, 0))
        print(content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        asyncio.run(echo())
```

When I am using `gzip.decompress(response)` its still compress! Ok, then I decided to use **unpack_from** and I have the following: (-29921, 8, 3513385716622361344)  from -> `unpack_from('hhl', response, 0)` or (121, 256, 140738648382701667)  from -> `unpack_from('hhl', content, 0)`. And again, maybe I should use another format characters('hhl') if it Python code([format characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)).

The final decoded or decompress data should looks like:

```
42["sb_odds_change","{\"id\":35285604,\"type\":\"match\",\"provider\":2,\"status\":1,\"timestamp\":1672170170534,\"markets\":[{\"id\":60,\"specifiers\":\"\",\"status\":0,\"provider\":2,\"meta\":{\"dataVersion\":46,\"lA\":0,\"lH\":0},\"timestamp\":1672170170534,\"outcomes\":[{\"id\":1,\"type\":\"predefined\",\"odds\":14,\"active\":false,\"state\":1},{\"id\":3,\"type\":\"predefined\",\"odds\":1.23,\"active\":false,\"state\":1},{\"id\":2,\"type\":\"predefined\",\"odds\":4.3,\"active\":false,\"state\":1}],\"state\":1,\"weight\":2},{\"id\":63,\"specifiers\":\"\",\"status\":0,\"provider\":2,\"meta\":{\"dataVersion\":46,\"lA\":0,\"lH\":0},\"timestamp\":1672170170534,\"outcomes\":[{\"id\":9,\"type\":\"predefined\",\"odds\":3.75,\"active\":false,\"state\":1}"]
```

**Any help will be greatly appreciated**! Maybe some one know, what should I am try.

**P.S.** Its only for me, I will get no money for this, if some one think so! Am really interesting to know, how or where I should find info to decode response from web socket. I am stuck be honestly.

Comment: If you're using a deflate extension, why do you need to manually decompress?

Comment: @tadman Friend I dont know what should be done right (( I just try to decode/decompress websocket response

Comment: Your 142-byte result is not compressed. There are far more zero and one bytes than other values. There's no way that your "received raw data" is producing the output you show with URLs. Furthermore there is no relation betwen that output with URLs and your desired output.

Comment: @MarkAdler if it not compressed, does it means its encoded? But why then I can decompress it and get result with ```Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(event.data.pack('c*')))```

Comment: The _result_ of decompression is not itself compressed, as you assert. You say "When I am using gzip.decompress(response) its still compress!" No, it is not "still compress".

Comment: @MarkAdler Oh, I see, than its encoded u think? Thx Mark